# Chrome asks for user / password on every site click with Digest authentication while IE, Edge and Firefox do not

Tags: google-chrome, http, authentication, digest-authentication

We have a site with a virtual folder where browsing is enabled. To access this folder digest authentication has been enabled so only some users can access it.

With IE, Edge and Firefox everything works as expected but with Chrome every click on a link shows the login / password dialog box (which works normally but as this is a directory browsing makes the experience painful).

If I change the authentication mechanism to Basic then everything works fine in all the browsers ... any insights about what can we do to move back to Digest authentications? (users are logging with their domain accounts so we don't want to send that information thru the wire).

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue under Incognito mode?

Comment: @shaochuancs: yes, it's happening too in the exact same way.